# How to run bash command after spinning up server?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

In a shell script, is there a way to run shell commands after spinning up a server? I'm trying to spin up nodejs, then launch the site in Chrome. But the browser only opens after the nodejs process over over.

```
#!/bin/sh

# run node server
node server.js

#launch web browser 
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'http://localhost:3000/'

exit 0
```

The requirement is to open Chrome and load what nodejs is serving (localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Spawn your server on the background (as a daemon).  Have your server write to some sort of lock file.  In your script, loop while the lock file isn't in existence (or use some other basic signaling mechanism) and then open chrome after being signalled.

Another solution would be to spawn the server on the background and sleep a bit before trying to open chrome.  It's tough to say which is better without knowing your requirements.

Comment: Any simple resource for spawning server on the background? I've never done it before.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy-noob way but you will need to reload your browser tab. You can start the browser and then run the node server.

```
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'http://localhost:3000/' && node server.js
```

Comment: Yeah I got that to work, but would love to not have to manually click refresh.